# How to check if an LXD container runs unprivileged?

Tags: lxc, lxd

I am [configuring my LXD containers to run unpriviledged as root](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxc/getting-started/#creating-unprivileged-containers-as-root).

**How can I check that they indeed run as such?**

Is it enough that `ps -ef` on the host shows that all processes running in containers follow the template

```
165536    5284  1104  0 12:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

(the first element is a uid)

or is there a `lxc` parameter which shows the "priviledge level" of a container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, is enough that you see that your UID is different than root and other users in your host for the processes running in your container. (setuid/setgid mapping magic)

Answer (score 3):

The page you linked to describes lxc not lxd. lxd is essentially a daemon process that provides access to lxc's features, in a higher-level/more-convenient way. I believe the answer for lxd is:

```
$ lxc config get your-container-name security.privileged
```

If that shows "true", then the container is privileged, else not.

Per [stgraber's post](https://www.stgraber.org/2016/03/19/lxd-2-0-your-first-lxd-container-312/) you can also query the set of privileged containers by running:

```
$ lxc list security.privileged=true
```

Comment: Thanks. The commands you mention show containers which are explicitly privileged. Running the second one with either `true` or `false` does not yield any results in my case (even though containers are running).

Comment: Thanks, this actually temporarily solved problem I faced described here:
https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/containers/2018-June/039176.html

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to check if a container is unprivileged from inside the LXD container by checking:

- `/proc/self/uid_map`
- `/proc/self/gid_map`

where it will show something like (root `0` mapped to user `1000000`):

```
# cat /proc/self/gid_map 
         0    1000000 1000000000
# cat /proc/self/uid_map 
         0    1000000 1000000000
```

(assuming `/etc/subuid` & `/etc/subgid` are correctly configured on the container host)

These values can be read by `root` or an unprivileged user.

- [source](https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/4249#issuecomment-947058403)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime you can just utilize `lxc-ls` to get a fancy listing telling you which of your containers run unprivileged and which are not:

```
# lxc-ls -f
NAME           STATE   AUTOSTART GROUPS IPV4 IPV6 UNPRIVILEGED 
container-name RUNNING 0         -      -    -    true
```